# How to return JSONP from a menu callback

Tags: 7

I can create JSON output using a menu hook using the `drupal_json_output` callback.

Example:

```
$items['page/%/json'] = array(
  'access callback'   => TRUE,
  'page callback'     => '_modulename_json',
  'delivery callback' => 'drupal_json_output'
);

function _modulename_json() {
  return array(
    'item1' => $field_item1[0]['safe_value'],
    'item2' => $field_item2[0]['safe_value'],
    'item3' => $item3,
    );
}
```

Output:

```
{"item1":"Field item1 content","item2":"Field item2 content","item3":"Item3 content"}
```

But I need to have JSONP, and am struggling to find an elegant solution... I have tried the code from the bottom of the [API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_json_output/7) page, it does the padding, but makes a mess of the content.

```
$response = array(1,2,3);
$callback = check_plain($_REQUEST['callback']);
// If its a jsonp callback request
if (isset($callback) && $callback != '') {
  $json_response = drupal_json_encode($response);
  echo $callback ."(". $json_response .");";
}
else {
  drupal_json_output($response);
}
```

Output this way:

```
callbackName({\u0022item1\u0022:\u0022Field item1 content\u0022,\u0022item2\u0022:\u0022Field item2 content\u0022,\u0022item3\u0022:\u0022Item3 content\u0022});"
```

Comment: i believe the problem is with line $json_response = drupal_json_encode($response); so that your code is double encoded remove this line and check

Comment: The issue is definitely related to this. But without it the output is `callbackName(Array);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array was being double encoded. First by the `$json_response = drupal_json_encode($response);` and then again by the menu delivery callback `'delivery callback' => 'drupal_json_output'`.

To fix this, remove the delivery callback, and use just `'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,`.

In the function change this:

```
if (isset($callback) && $callback != '') {
  $json_response = drupal_json_encode($response);
  echo $callback ."(". $json_response .");";
}
```

to this:

```
if (isset($callback) && $callback != '') {
  $json_response = drupal_json_encode($response);
  drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
  echo $callback . "(" . $json_response . ");";
  drupal_exit();
}
```